# What can be read from memory in a C# application

Tags: c#, memory

I know that any application running (whether it is built with C#, C, C++, Java, etc) will have elements exposed in memory. I'm curious as to how to control what and how it is exposed in memory?

I'm curious because I know that many games get hacked or modified by a user viewing the contents in memory of the game and altering them. I just want to know more details around how this works. I know special programs must be used to even dive into the memory and there are conversions and stuff that must happen for it to even be some what readable.

Let's take a extremely simple example and I'll ask some questions about it.

```
using System.Security;

static class Program2
{
    private static SecureString fSecureString;

    public static string fPublicString = "Test123";

    private static string fPrivateString = "321tesT";

    static void Main2()
    {

    }
}

class TestClass
{
    private string fInstancedPrivateString;
    public TestClass()
    {
        fInstancedPrivateString = "InstancedSet";
    }

    private string DoSomething()
    {
        return fInstancedPrivateString.ToLower();
    }
}
```

}

Given the code above, I imagine that fPublicString is pretty visible to see. What elements can someone reading memory see? Can they read the variable name or do they just see an memory address and an assigned value (Test123). What about Functions like DoSomething that are inside an instanced class? Can someone see that in memory and write malicious code to execute it at their will?

I'm just curious as to how much of this I need to keep in mind while writing applications (or games). I understand the general idea of the accessor properties (public/private/etc) and their relation to other code having visibility to it, but I'm curious if they have any bearing on how it is represented in memory.

My final question will be very specific: EverQuest (game) has a hack called MacroQuest which from my understanding reads memory by having the proper offsets and can then execute code from the EQ client side or simply change values stored in memory for the client. How did EQ get this so wrong? Was it poor programming on their end? A technology limitation that is sort of resolved now? Or can this technically be done with virtually every piece of software that is written with the right amount of knowledge?

Over all I guess I could probably use a good tutorial, article, or book that provides some details on how code looks in memory etc.

Comment: As soon as someone runs your program on their local computer, they can view what is in the memory.  There isn't a way to stop that.  You can make it more difficult using certain techniques, but it will never be impossible.

Comment: As for the EQ hack, most apps -- particularly ones written in C or C++ -- have this vulnerability to some degree, because any variable that's not a local has its address, or at least the address of a pointer to it, somewhat fixed at link time.  It's a bit harder in interpreted languages (and on VM'ish platforms like Java and .net) because the addresses can more easily vary, and can be changed basically at the runtime's whim.  But there's still a table of objects in there somewhere, and the ID (read: location) of the object you're looking for isn't quite random.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. @cHao, are you saying that the more local variables I use and the less global variables the better?

Comment: Local variables are less fixed, but they're still not terribly hard to find.  They're just more transient as you get closer to the top of the call stack, but still are tied to a stack frame.  The locals in `main`, though, are almost as fixed in location as globals are.  They're still pretty easy to find, if you know where the bottom of the stack is; they just won't have symbols in the binary jumping up and screaming "I'm over here!"  :)  (Though you can strip symbols to keep that from happening with globals in some cases, there are other cases where they have to be visible.)

Comment: Cool thanks! Last question, could someone use information in memory to somehow execute my code? Whether the function is public or private etc.

Comment: Public/private/protected are just compiler stuff, there to make it easier to write code that does the right thing.  To the CPU, it's all the same.  If a hacker can make a public function run, they can do the same with a private one.  And making a function run is as simple as altering the image to call whatever function you want.  The CPU has mechanisms (NX for example) that make this harder, but they're bypassable if you have control over the process's address space.  (They're made more to protect programs from remote attacks than to keep local processes from subverting each other.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that your application's memory can be read should not be something a "normal" developer needs to worry about. The number of users that are able to exploit this in a useful way are very few (in the grand scheme) and it only really matters for *sensitive* parts of your application anyway (licensing, passwords, and other personally identifiable information). Otherwise, the risk is really negligible.

If the effort of protecting it can't be justified by the cost of doing so then why should the person/group/etc *paying* to have it built worry. It isn't worth investing the time to care when there's always a ton of other things that could otherwise use the time investment.

Should Notepad or MS Word care that you can write a sniffer to listen to what is being typed? Probably not, and why? Because it really doesn't effect the bottom line or pose any realistic risk.